# how to change service callback timeout dynamicly

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-callbacks

I need to set my service's callback timeouts
but i cannot find where are they defined.
this needs to be hardcoded.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "callback timeout". What behaviour do you want to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to specify a callback timeout. If you use a per session instance context then your channel session will have a timeout, but this is not the same thing. For clarity can I you just confirm what behavior you expect to see on a callback timeout?

For example, after timeout then the service is unable to callback to the client?

I have not seen this behavior - in my experience the callback channel will be available when the service executes the callback and this will work after any amount of time.